# How do I search for a certain line in a json file with a key word?

Tags: python, json, search, keyword

I want to know how to search for a line that has a certain name. This is my .txt file with json:

```
{"people": [{"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}, {"name": "Larry", "website": "google.com", "from": "Michigan"}, {"name": "Tim", "website": "apple.com", "from": "Alabama"}]}
```

This is my code

```py
import json

file = open('data.txt', "r")
read = file.read()
y = json.loads(read)

first = y["people"][0]
second = y["people"][1]
third = y["people"][2]

print(y["people"][0]["name"])
```

That prints out Scott, but is there a way to search the json file for the line with the name Scott? Ive tried print(y["people"]["name": "Scott"]) but that didnt work. I want the output to be {"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}

Comment: if i understand you correctly, You are trying to print list of json which has name Scott. then [ jobj  if jobj['name'] == 'Scott' for jobj in y['people']]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the list. e.g.

```
>>> people = y['people']
>>> people_named_scott = [p for p in people if p['name'] == 'Scott']
>>> people_named_scott
[{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]
```

Comment: Alright, Thanks! this worked. Ill add a check to it in 7 minutes. Just so I get this straight:

Comment: p for p in people means it searches each row?

Comment: @maxmeinz, check out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: So its like a range loop that searches it each time there is a new row? (what I mean by a row is {"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"})

Answer (score 1):

You can store the person's information whose name is `Scott` in a list.

Python code:

```
import json

file = open('data.txt', "r")
read = file.read()
y = json.loads(read)
people = y["people"]
lines = [person for person in people if person["name"] == "Scott"]
if len(lines) == 0:
    print("Scott is not found")
else:
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

`data.txt`:

```
{"people": [{"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}, {"name": "Larry", "website": "google.com", "from": "Michigan"}, {"name": "Tim", "website": "apple.com", "from": "Alabama"}]}
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}
```

Comment: is there a way to display an error message if the line with the name "Scott" does not exist?

Comment: @maxmeinz, updated the code. If `lines` does not contain any element then we can show a message to the user. Do you want to throw an error?

Comment: Oh ok, it works! Because if you dont do that then it just prints [], and that is 0 lines, right?

Comment: @maxmeinz, Yes, if `lines` is empty,  then there is no line including the name `Scott`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using jmespath (https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, You are trying to print list of json which has name Scott.

```
print([jobj if jobj['name']=='Scott' for jobj in y['people']])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this where it iterates all people and then returns the first person with the matching name.

```
def getPersonByName(allInfo, name):
    for info in allInfo["people"]:
        if info["name"] == name:
            return info

allInfo = {"people": [{"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}, {"name": "Larry", "website": "google.com", "from": "Michigan"}, {"name": "Tim", "website": "apple.com", "from": "Alabama"}]}

print(getPersonByName(allInfo, "Scott"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the builtin [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function combined with a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression for the solution.

```
data={"people": [{"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}, {"name": "Larry", "website": "google.com", "from": "Michigan"}, {"name": "Tim", "website": "apple.com", "from": "Alabama"}]}
print(filter(lambda x:x['name'] == 'Scott',data['people']))
# gives [{'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska', 'name': 'Scott'}]
```